# Date comparison compatible with H2 and Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, h2

I have to compare two dates with SQL. I have to do it in H2 and Oracle with the same sentence.

I have tried with a lot of sentences:

```
TRUNC(CONTACT_END_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')  >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

When the `CONTACT_END_DATE` value is: `9999-12-31`, H2 gives me this error code -> `[22018-170]`

In H2 works perfectly this:

```
CONTACT_END_DATE  >= SYSDATE
```

But in Oracle the condition is not met. I can't modify the Oracle SYSDATE configuration.

If I try this:

```
TRUNC(CONTACT_END_DATE)  >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

H2 says me that It needs more arguments.

I also tried this:

```
TO_CHAR(CONTACT_END_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:ss') >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:ss');
```

But my H2 version doesn't support 'TO_CHAR' function.

Comment: *"H2 says me that It needs more arguments."* what is the **exact error message**?

Comment: You're using an archaic version of H2 from 2012, do you really can't use a more recent version that has additional Oracle compatibility functions?

Comment: @APC  Invalid parameter count for "TRUNC", expected count: "2";

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov I can't change H2 version because this kind of issues are controlled by my company architecture team

Comment: Oracle would expect you to use `TRUNC(CONTACT_END_DATE, 'DD')  >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD' )` if you are providing two arguments and expect to truncate to the beginning of the day. This could be simplified to just `CONTACT_END_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD' )` since you don't need to truncate both sides. No idea on the equivalent H2 syntax.

Comment: Presumably it's also the "company architecture team" who are requiring you to write one set of code which runs against both H2 and Oracle. They cannot have it both ways (literally).

Comment: @MT0 - in Oracle `trunc(sysdate)` and `trunc(sysdate, 'DD')` are the same thing. But it might be the solution to the H2 issue (assuming `trunc` works with dates in whatever version of H2 the Seeker is using).

Comment: @MT0 I also tried that and I got the same error code [22018-170].
Data conversion error converting "2020-01-16 11:29:48.259"

Comment: @APC I know, that's why I explicitly stated that was for if you are using two arguments (since the OP stated that H2 was expecting two arguments and they seemed to be trying various combinations of `'DD/MM/YYYY'` as the second argument rather than using `'DD'` as Oracle would accept).

Comment: What data type is your `CONTRACT_END_DATE` column? Is it a `DATE` data type or are you storing it as a `VARCHAR2` or `CHAR` that just happens to store a date string?

Comment: @MT0 It is DATE type.